Python3 subprocess.run - how to print/capture output (stdout, stderr) while also allowing for user input (stdin)
I am trying to create a function that can run bash commands from python for convenience. I'd like to output any stdout, while also storing all stdout/stderr for reference. However I seem to run into issues when userinput is involved. In the following example, stdout fails to print (nothing shows at all) until enter is hit which immediately skips stdin.
Setting the subprocess stdin=subprocess.PIPE doesn't help, this skips any userinput entirely
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    result = {}
    try:
        process = subprocess.run(
            command,
            shell=True,
            stdin=None, #setting to subprocess.PIPE skips userinput entirely
            stdout=None,
            stderr=None,
            universal_newlines=True,
            capture_output=True
        )

        result = {
            "returncode": process.returncode,
            "stdout": process.stdout,
            "stderr": process.stderr
        }

        #when a command requests userinput, this doesn't seem to print UNTIL enter is hit
        print(process.stdout)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred: {e}")

    return result

#Example: has an issue when run a second time, because stdin for existing file overwrite
result = run_command(f"ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -N '' -f ./ssh_key_test")
print(result)



I see no benefit in using Python for this. Just write a shell script

You should use subprocess.Popen(). subprocess.run() doesn't return until the program exits.

You don't need the stdout and stderr options when you use capture_output=True.

In this particular case, there are two different approaches:

Delete the key files before generating
Use the yes command

Of these two approaches, I like the first one because it works cross platform. The second approach only works for those operating systems with the yes command available.
Delete Key Files
import subprocess
import pathlib

# Removing any existing keys
filename = "./ssh_key_test"
pathlib.Path(filename).unlink(missing_ok=True)
pathlib.Path(f"{filename}.pub").unlink(missing_ok=True)

# Generate
cmd = subprocess.run(
    ["ssh-keygen", "-t", "ed25519", "-N", '', "-f", filename],
)

Use the yes Command
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.run(
    "yes | ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -N '' -f ./ssh_key_test",
    shell=True,
)

